# Laravel mail configuration if using providers

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want do a helper who send mails, i was start by doing provider and a custom class for my helper.

1. my provider register function:

   ```
   public function register()
   {
       $this->app->bind('mailer.helper', function (Application $app){
           return new MailerHelper($app->make('mailer'));
       });
   }
   ```
2. my helper function:

   ```
   class MailerHelper implements SelfHandling{

   /** @var Mailer $mailer */
   protected $mailer;

   public function __construct(Mailer $mailer) {
       $this->mailer=$mailer;
   }


   public function sendFromContact(array $date){

       $this->mailer->send('email_templates/contact', $date, function (Message $message){
           $message->setTo('stroia.laurentiu92@gmail.com');
           $message->setFrom('contact@dianabotezan.ro','Contact website Diana Botezan');
           $message->setSubject('Forumlar contact');
       });
   }
   }
   ```
3. my configuration from config/mail.php:

   `return [
       'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
       'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
       'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
       'from' => ['address' => null, 'name' => null],
       'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl'),
       'username' => env('my_gmal@gmail.com'),
       'password' => env('mypassword'),
       'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
       'pretend' => false,
   ]'`

and the problem is laravel have a bad configuration, here is my track from what he try to do:

`Connection could not be established with host 127.0.0.1 [Connection refused #111]`

`1. in StreamBuffer.php line 265
2. at Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->_establishSocketConnection() in StreamBuffer.php line 62
3. at Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->initialize(array('protocol' => null, 'host' => '127.0.0.1', 'port' => '2525', 'timeout' => '30', 'blocking' => '1', 'tls' => false, 'type' => '1')) in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 113`

here you can observe he have other config then I set it. What i do wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've put your configuration in the wrong place.

Instead of editing the `config/mail.php` file directly, you should put your mail configuration settings in the `.env` file at the root of your project.

You can [see here in the sample file shipped with laravel](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/.env.example#L14-L19).

Comment: thank you! but could you say for what is it config/mail.php ?

Comment: `config/mail.php` simply pulls in the information in your `.env` file, using the `env` helper.